# Disable keyboard dismiss from screen when focusout from Textinput - react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if there is a way to show keyboard always if it focuses out from the TextInput in react native.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `TextInput` by a `ScrollView` and then use the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` prop in `ScrollView` to avoid dismissing the keyboard and handle the keyboard dismiss by using `Keyboard.dismiss()` function in somewhere else.
Read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboarddismissmode) for more documentation.

Comment: Is there any way to show keyboard through javascript and disable dismiss of the keyboard from the screen?

Comment: By using the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop the keyboard doesn't dismiss in the screen. You can read the document of keyboard methods and APIs here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/keyboard.html#keyboard